# python timezone differs from standard

Tags: python, timezone, timezone-offset

I have an unusual experience in working with timezones. I have to format a python datetime object to `iso8601` format. In linux `date --iso-8601=s` would give you the result: `2017-12-11T12:30:07+03:30`. In python I have tried using `isoformat` method without setting any timezone:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=44, second=25, microsecond=0).isoformat()
```

But it returns `'2017-01-01T12:44:25'` which doesn't include time difference with UTC; I guess because it's a naive datetime object. I tried using explicit timezone:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=44, second=25, microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Tehran')).isoformat()
```

But surprisingly I got `'2017-01-01T12:44:25+03:26'` which is 4 minutes behind.

I checked my machine timezone with command `date +'%:z %Z'` and the output was `+03:30 +0330`. Timezone names are `Iran` and `Asia/Tehran` regarding to commands `find /usr/share/zoneinfo/* -type f -exec sh -c "diff -q /etc/localtime '{}' > /dev/null && echo {}" \` and `cat /etc/timezone` respectively.

In other side, I checked result of method `pytz.timezone` for `Iran` and `Asia/Tehran` timezone names; I got `LMT+3:26:00 STD` for both situations. I can use `tzoffset` with 12600 as time difference seconds, but daylight saving affects this; which I want to be independent from.

I also tried to find offset seconds:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=44, second=25, microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Tehran'))
>>> tzlocal.get_localzone().utcoffset(d)
datetime.timedelta(0, 12360)
```

And without timezone:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=44, second=25, microsecond=0)
>>> tzlocal.get_localzone().utcoffset(d)
datetime.timedelta(0, 12600)
```

But as I mentioned, if I don't set the timezone, I can't get the time difference from `isoformat`.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is it different in python timezones from standard?
2. How can I handle this ISO formatting with all the criteria?